# GeoLiteCityv6.dat seems to return different data from a day ago

Tags: geoip, maxmind, freegeoip

I regularly check the values being returned from the GeoLityCityv6.dat data file in unit tests.
Today it is returning completely different values from yesterday

For example

24.24.24.24

Used to return 
CountryCode [US], CountryName [United States], ContinentCode [NA], ContinentName [North America],

today it returns 
CountryCode [CN], CountryName [China], ContinentCode [AS], ContinentName [Asia], City [V±!S%Õ¨áNY], regionCode [3]

200.24.24.40

user to return, 
CountryCode [CO], CountryName [Columbia], ContinentCode [SA], ContinentName [South America], City [Medell], regionCode [02]

today returnes 
CountryCode [DE], CountryName [Germany], ContinentCode [EU], ContinentName [Europe], City []?ïù102], regionCode [3420]

121.46.168.148

used to return
CountryCode [CN], CountryName [China], ContinentCode [AS], ContinentName [Asia], City [Guangzhou], regionCode [30]

today returns
CountryCode [JO], CountryName [Jordan], ContinentCode [AS], ContinentName [Asia],  City [null], regionCode [gbao]

62.178.96.142

used to return
CountryCode [AT], CountryName [Austria], ContinentCode [EU], ContinentName [Europe]
today returns

CountryCode [CO], CountryName [Colombia], ContinentCode [SA], ContinentName [South America], City [Ì}$é307], regionCode [751]

When I look up these IP Addresses on maxmind.org home page I get the old data not the new data

Comment: What API are you using to read the database?

Answer (score 1):

This was a corrupt database file. The issue has been corrected. Please download a new version.